# Unsupported font in Firefox- Yore Script?

Tags: css

My CSS code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Yore Script';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: lighter;
src: local('Yore Script'), url("/Users/abricker/Desktop/simple-master 3 copy     2/fonts/yore_script-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("/Users/abricker/Desktop/simple-master 3 copy     2/fonts/Yore Script.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/Users/abricker/Desktop/simple-master 3 copy     2/fonts/yore_script-webfont.svg") format("svg");
}
```

Firefox is not picking this up at all. My other fonts are working correctly though (journal and geo sans light) and they are coded the exact same way. Thoughts? Does Firefox not support certain fonts??

Answer (score 0):

Firefox's font display libraries can handle almost any font that complies with the standards.  The issue is not Firefox's font display libraries but rather that it cannot *access* your font.

Are you sure your URLs in the `src` section are correct?  Why do the path names have so many spaces in them?  What do you get when you type

```
ls -l '/Users/abricker/Desktop/simple-master 3 copy     2/fonts/yore_script-webfont.woff'
```

in your shell?  Does that file exist?